# How to scramble/shuffle/randomize all the letters of a string in python except the first and the last letter?

Tags: string, python-3.x, shuffle

For example :

```
Example 1:
string = "Jack and the bean stalk."
updated_string = "Jcak and the baen saltk."
Example 2:
string = "Hey, Do you want to boogie? Yes, Please."
updated_string = "Hey, Do you wnat to bogoie? Yes, Palsee."
```

Now this string is stored in a file.
I want to read this string from the file. And write the updated string back in the file at same positions.
Letters of each word of the string with length greater than 3 must be scrambled/shuffled  while keeping first and last letter as it is. Also if there is any punctuation mark the punctuation mark stays as it is.

My approach:

```
import random
with open("path/textfile.txt","r+") as file:
    file.seek(0)
    my_list = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        word = line.split()
        my_list.append(word)

scrambled_list =[]
for i in my_list:
    if len(i) >3:
        print(i)
        s1 = i[1]
        s2 = i[-1]
        s3 = i[1:-1]
        random.shuffle(s3)
        y = ''.join(s3)
        z = s1+y+s2+' '
        print(z)
```

Comment: What's not working/missing in your approach? Please edit your question with that information

Comment: My approach is too vague. I am successfully able to extract each word from the file. Now I am unsure how to skip punctuation marks and how to shuffle the words like Surprising, and keeping their first and last letter and the punctuation intact while shufflling all others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
from random import shuffle
import string

punctuation = tuple(string.punctuation)

for line in file.readlines():   #Iterate lines
    res = []
    for i in line.split():      #Split sentence to words
        punch = False
        if len(i) >= 4:         #Check if word is greater than 3 letters
            if i.endswith(punctuation):    #Check if words ends with punctuation 
                val = list(i[1:-2])        #Exclude last 2 chars
                punch = True
            else:
                val = list(i[1:-1])        #Exclude last 1 chars
            shuffle(val)               #Shuffle letters excluding the first and last.
            if punch:
                res.append("{0}{1}{2}".format(i[0], "".join(val), i[-2:]))
            else:
                res.append("{0}{1}{2}".format(i[0], "".join(val), i[-1]))
        else:
            res.append(i)
    print(" ".join(res))
```